# "Error: spawn EACCES" showing on cordova build android project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

[Click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKP5W.png)

How to resolve this problem?? Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have any hook on hooks folder?

Comment: try with sudo command. Its for root user.

Comment: no..just updated coddova version and updated jdk version to jdk1.8.0_131.
after updating both, I am getting this error.

Comment: @Hiten can you please give me the command which you want to say..

Comment: sudo cordova build android

Comment: @Hiten tried but same error showing.

Comment: okay.
Then please remove the platform and add it again and then try.

Comment: @Hiten tried with remove & add platform. still same error showing

Comment: also tried this following commands..still same error occurred
1.cordova create myApp org.apache.cordova.myApp myApp
2.cd myApp
3.cordova platform add android
4.cordova build android --verbose

Comment: what is your node and cordova version ?

Comment: cordova-> 7.0.1  node->6.3.0

Comment: found another message <br/>
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/rubeldebnath/Desktop/android-sdk-macosx <br/>
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home <br/>
Running command: "/Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle" -p /Users/rubeldebnath/Documents/mytestapp/myApp/platforms/android wrapper -b /Users/rubeldebnath/Documents/mytestapp/myApp/platforms/android/wrapper.gradle <br/>
Error: spawn EACCES

Comment: okay.
then create the new project and then replace the "www" folder from your existing project to your new project and try to run it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Preview and `chmod 777 /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 3.0\ Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.0-milestone-1/bin/gradle` fixed it for me. Gradle versions might vary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried all sort of permission change and it still didn't work. My problem started with the update of android studio which in turn forced me to update Cordova. Finally I got it working by downloading the latest [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?utm_source=android-studio) (2.3.2) and installing it. I am also using Mac.